# buffer name of opened directory in netrw disappears sometimes

Tags: buffers, netrw

I usually open a directory in vim with command `:e path-of-dir`. Because the plugin Netrw is included by default, this will be taken over by it and a netrw window will open with the content of the dir.

But recently I have found that the buffer name of an opened directory would become `[No Name]` sometimes. I can still run netrw operations in it, its name just gone.

The versions I am using are `vim 8.1` and `netrw v165`. I never had this problem in vim 7. Have you guys ever encounter this problem? Is it a bug or just designed to be so? Is there any workaround, since it is a pain for attempts to restore dirs between vim sessions?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Is there any observable pattern for those directories where it fails?

Comment: It happens every time when restoring dirs from a saved session. Before `:mksession`, set the netrw buffer to be listed via `:set bl`, then it will be included into the session file. Then when restored, the dirs are opened, but all become `[No Name]`, which couldn't be recognized for the next session saving.

Comment: But why would you set `bl`? That doesnt make sense.

Comment: that is because `:mksession` will only save it when that is set.

Comment: Right—but why save netrw buffers? They aren’t meant to be

Comment: that is a way to keep opened directories between sessions.

Comment: I understand why that might be desirable, but based on how complex netrw is (have you seen its help file?), I would argue that setting `buflisted` is likely to cause bizarre and unwanted interactions. If you can live with this issue, do so, but I would suggest adapting your workflow slight to not needing to save/restore netrw during session. (FWIW, I have netrw open for seconds at a time, as I navigate to a file then open it. I don't leave the file explorer open, as it doesn't add value to my limited editing space.)

Comment: @Terry I have a similar problem. When I open a directory on the command line `vim .`, then it starts 2 buffers: the directory page AND a [No Name] buffer. Vim shows me the netrw page usable and all but the status line says both `[No Name]` and `[Netrw]`. This does not seems like a problem but the thing is that the current buffer is actually no name. So if I go on a file and then `CTRL-^` to go back to the netrw page, I end up on an empty screen `[No Name]`. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @Mig Unfortunately, no, I haven't found a solution. In your case, you could remember the netrw path and use ":e path" to open it again explicitly, instead of using `CTRL-^`.

Comment: @Terry `set nohidden` fixed it for me.